# To hide a class in angular

Tags: css, angular

I am trying to position the ::before ::after css selector to the popup modal whenever the box is hovered
That works but the arrow class gets appended when I click on box and modal opens up.

I tried removing the class

```
elRef.nativeElement.queryselector(".arrow").remove()
```

Also adding a display none class

```
elRef.nativeElement.queryselector(".arrow").classList.add("hide")

 .hide{
       display: none
 }
```

I want the arrow to be attcahed to the box is hovered and popup opens,  not when the box is clicked and popup opens

Reproducible stackblitz

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ytnzmy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First you will need to move your hide class to `style.css` second you will need to remove hide class on modal close like

```
 this.element.nativeElement.querySelector('.arrow').classList.remove('hide');
```

[demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-tqplr9)

Answer (score 1):

Firstly, your syntax needs correction. It should be as below

```
this.element.nativeElement.querySelector(".arrow").classList.add("hide");
```

Secondly, since angular has [view encapsulation](https://angular.io/api/core/ViewEncapsulation) enabled as default, your styles needs to go inside `hello.component.ts`

[Update Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-dbprn1)

Comment: but once I hide the arrow class after that whenever I again hover then the arrow disappers :)

Comment: @Enthu you will need to remove hide class on modal close check my answer for demo